# Advertising on Super User (2015)

Tags: discussion, advertising

I just posted our advertisement to Super User:

https://meta.superuser.com/a/8079/22536

Please **upvote it** so that it reaches the required threshold of 6 votes to get displayed, thanks!

---

The ad itself can still be modified, don't hesitate to bring our ideas/designs/images at [Advertising on Super User (2014)](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/851).
Do you know other QA site where it would make sense to advertise, potentially with a different ad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks all, the threshold has been reached!

Feel free to vote more just in case.

---

I was thinking about posting another ad to StackOverflow (library and web services recommendations).

But [the StackOverflow ads rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) only allow for open source projects, and stackexchange is not even open source software.

Comment: You are confusing the [community promotion ads](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7438/community-promotion-ads-2014/8079#8079) program that most sites have with the [Open Source Initiative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) specific to Stack Overflow. You are correct that the SO Open Source advertising is for open source software only, but SO does *not* have Community Promotion ads for "library and web services recommendations."

Answer (score 2):

It's a new year, time for new ads:)

I've got an ad running on Super User, please upvote if you can (once it reaches 6, it'll show)

https://meta.superuser.com/a/11136/269798

Here's what it looks like,

[image: Love software? Visit Software Recommendations]

Note: At the time of this writing, the other ad for SR  does *not* meet the image requirements for the image dimensions thus the reason for this one.

Comment: Upvoted! I suggest first getting it over 6 as our priority, and maybe replacing it with a less generic ad as our second priority :-) Thanks!