# Advertising on Stack sites

Tags: discussion, advertising

Many Stack sites have started accepting applications for community advertisements.

Where should we advertise?
Not all sites run these campaigns, but anyway here is a list of sites that we might want to reach to, campaign or not:

- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7080/1480)
- [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9012/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12379/200337)
- [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6840/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- others?

(if you find their campaign page please list it above thanks!)

Please submit your designs, and we talk about them and post them.

Feel free to reuse [last year's advertisement ideas](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/851).

Comment: Only graduated sites have these community advertisement campaigns. This includes [su] and [sf] but not [so] (which also has community ads, but they cannot be used to advertise our site). Beta sites and [patents.se] have no such thing.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing Ask Patents and beta sites, as Gilles says, they don't have community ads.

Comment: Sure thanks! :-)

Comment: For [wordpress.se], see discussion: [Community Promotion Ad on WordPress Development SE?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2331/60)

Answer (score 8):

After a week without proposals, I got bold and reused last year's ad:

[image: Software Recommendations Stack Exchange]

Please upvote on the sites below (posted by me or by others), thanks!

- https://meta.superuser.com/a/9055/22536
- https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2337/22061
- https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3367/2305
- https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7080/1480

Still feel free to post your own designs!

Comment: Thanks, upvoted!